# Generate CSV/TXT file from named zone file

Tags: dns, grep, sed, csv

I am in need of generating a csv/txt file from a zone file on a named DNS server.

For examples I would like to generate a list of the hostname and IP from the zone file

From this

```
monkey          A   192.168.1.1
bear            A   192.168.1.2
shark           A   192.168.2.1
bird            A   192.168.3.1
lion            A   192.168.4.1
```

To This

```
monkey,192.168.1.1
bear,192.168.1.2
shark,192.168.2.1
bird,192.168.3.1
lion,192.168.4.1
```

How can I achieve this, using Sed and Grep? Does anyone have a script that they use to do a similar task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you would consider using awk for this:

```
awk '{print $1,$3}' OFS=, infile
```

If you are set on `sed` here is one way you can do it (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/([^ \t]+)\s+A\s+([^ \t]+)/\1,\2/' infile
```

Or with GNU coreutils:

```
<infile tr -s ' ' | cut --output-delimiter=, -d' ' -f1,3
```

Output:

```
monkey,192.168.1.1
bear,192.168.1.2
shark,192.168.2.1
bird,192.168.3.1
lion,192.168.4.1
```

Comment: Brilliant, both examples using sed & awk worked great! Cheers.