# Generate report for DNS zone file entries

Tags: linux, bash, dns, grep, sed

EDIT: Some clarification. What I'm doing is I have a python script that will connect to my DNS servers and then run a bash script which is located in home to grep for all the A's in *something.com then grep for something else that I can't list out. After that I have either the 1st or 2nd parts of what I listed below run. The results from that get saved on a file on my computer.

It looks like this:

```
grep "A" *something.com | grep <something> | awk/sed <either the first or 2nd example>
```

The 1st script will give me

```
something.something.com:DNSentry    IP
```

2nd

```
something.something.com
DNSentry   IP
```

What I need is to make it looks like this.

```
DNSentry.something.something.com    IP
```

---

I've been trying to finish a script that will generate a DNS report. So far I have two ways of doing this and the results are this. Currently I have a long string of greps, awk and sed.

When using the string from this post I'm able to generate this. [Generate CSV/TXT file from named zone file](https://superuser.com/questions/598095/generate-csv-txt-file-from-named-zone-file)

```
org1.com:entry1       IP
org1.com:entry2       IP
org2.com:entry1       IP
org2.com:entry2       IP
etc.
```

I also have a script that can generate this by using this:

```
grep <pattern> | awk -F: '{if ($1 != last) {print "";print $1; last = $1} print $2}' | sed "s/A//"
```

I'm getting close with what I need but when I try and add the org.com to the line it will place it directly after the IP instead of the entry.

```
org1.com
entry1        IP
entry2        IP

org2.com
entry1        IP
entry2        IP

etc.
```

What I need to get is for the output to look like this

```
entry1.org1.com    IP
entry2.org1.com    IP

entry1.org2.com    IP
entry2.org2.com    IP
```

Comment: This is not a script-writing service. You should show us what you tried, where you failed,  that you made an effort.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to posting here. I've been beating my head against a wall trying to do this and learn as I go. In the future I'll be more clear in what I have done, failed and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not perfect or bulletproof, but maybe this gives you a start:

```
awk '/A/{print $1"."FILENAME"\t"$NF}' *something.com
```

that means, match lines from file with 'A' in the line, 
and print the FILENAME, the hostname of the record and the IP address.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Where would I plug this into? I can't list out what the orgs are but they are the file names and have multiple .'s in them. My 1st grep is grep "A" *org.com

Comment: I am confused. I've read like 20 times or so your question and still dont get it 100% what you want to do. Can you re-edit your question to be a little more specific plz ? Where did you do your first grep filter ? In a folder ? In a file ? If you can edit your initial question, perhaps it would make more sense for me or others.

Comment: Updated my post. I hope it helps clear stuff up

Comment: I've just reedit my answer. does that makes more sense to you?

Comment: HUGE HELP! I can def take it from here and finish this up. Thanks a ton!